# How to create a blob in Android HTML5 app

Tags: android, pdf, cordova, blob

My server spits out the source of a PDF. With XHR2 I request that code using `xhr.responseType = 'blob';` For iOS I then just use

```
blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: "application/pdf"});
```

and then save it using Phonegap's Filewriter. When I then open the saved file, I have a perfect PDF. I simply can't get anything similar to work on Android. My last attempt was:

```
             if (!window.BlobBuilder && window.WebKitBlobBuilder){
                window.BlobBuilder = window.WebKitBlobBuilder;
                var bb = new window.BlobBuilder();
                bb.append(this.response);
                blob = bb.getBlob("application/pdf");}
```

since Android coughed over just plain 'BlobBuilder'. That duly creates a PDF which FileWriter then saves. The files structure is presumably OK as a PDF since PDF readers open it without complaint. Unfortunately, the PDF is completely blank.
I just don't seem to be able to get my elderly head around whatever is required by Android.